# Can't seem to use select() with stdin in C

Tags: c, select

I have a client/server implementation where i need to read inputs from terminal as well as receiving events from server with the socket, however select() dont seem to work with stdin:

```
static void get_active_inputs(cli_ctrl_t ctrl)
  {
      errno = 0;
      ctrl.max_fd = (0 > ctrl.control_socket) ? ctrl.control_socket:0;
      FD_ZERO(&ctrl.read_fds);
      FD_SET(ctrl.control_socket, &ctrl.read_fds);
      FD_SET(0, &ctrl.read_fds);
      if ((select(ctrl.max_fd + 1, &ctrl.read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0 && \
              (errno != EINTR)) {
          perror("select()");
          exit(84);
      }
  }

static int shell(cli_ctrl_t ctrl)
  {
      char **toks = NULL;
      char *line = NULL;
      size_t len = 0;
      size_t i = 0;

      while (1) {
          get_active_inputs(ctrl);
          if (FD_ISSET(ctrl.control_socket, &ctrl.read_fds)) {
              printf("Got message from server\n");
          }
          if (FD_ISSET(0, &ctrl.read_fds)) {
            printf("Got inputs from client\n");
            getline(&line, &len, stdin);
            toks = sep_tok(line, "  \n\r\t");
            for (; commands[i].str != NULL; i++) {
                if (strcmp(commands[i].str, toks[0]) == 0) {
                    commands[i].ptr(&ctrl, toks);
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return (0);
  }
```

It wont enter on the "(FD_ISSET(0, &ctrl.read_fds)) { }" if section although i watched the return of select() when i typed on terminal and it returns 1, but dont enter on the FD_ISSET

Comment: You're passing `ctrl` by _value_, meaning `get_active_inputs` receives a _copy_ of it. The caller's `ctrl` object (also passed in by value) is never touched at all.

Comment: What is `cli_ctrl_t`? I assume it's not a reference type, so you'd copy it by value.

Comment: yes that was it thanks guys!

Comment: Doing buffered I/O on `stdin` when `STDIN_FILENO` becomes readable also seems error-prone.

Comment: regarding: `errno = 0;`  Since the function: `select()` sets errno, why is the code changing it first?

Comment: what is `ctrl`?   Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: @user3629249 ctrl is just a control struct with my control_socket, some uuid, my readable_fds for FD_x macros,;

Comment: @Useless could you explain a bit more with I/O buffering when FD_SET/seleclt/FD_ISSET macro tell me it is readable,  is this about the getline() that could be error-prone?

Comment: Yes, stdin has its own internal buffer. Since you're testing whether STDIN_FILENO is readable, you should just read directly from it.